# Move out html from ng-if blocks in template

Tags: angularjs

It's probably dead simple but I don't how it's to be done.
I have a pretty long html template for my very generic directive.

Just for styling reasons there is some (pseudo) code like:

```
<p ng-if="type===1">
    {{entity.name}}
    <button ng-click="someAction(entity)">
</p>
<p ng-if="type===2">
    <img href="" ng-click="someAction(entity)">
    {{entity.title}}
</p>
<p ng-if="type===3">
   <a href="#" ng-click="someAction(entity)">{{entity.name}}</a>
   {{entity.title}}
</p>
```

So as you can see all parts within the ng-if blocks show some attributes of entity in some way and somehow 'someAction' is called.

Is there any simple way to move out the html within the ng-if blocks into a separate file and including it here just to keep a better overview? There's no need to create  a new scope or anything else, it should just parse the moved html as it would have been written like within the template.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: looks like you are looking for `ng-include` though, but then again, that creates a new scope, just like `ng-if`. If you need a more robust solution, probably look into some routing components? one good candidate will be `ui-router`. http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`ngInclude`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude). The common content can be moved to a HTML and included via this directive.

Comment: but won't I have any issues with my 'entity' then as ngInclude will create a new scope?